# how to do select the rows with same value across columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with 9 columns. Each column has values 0,1.

1 -means outlier.

It's outliers according to 9 different algorithms.
I want to select those true outliers, the following query does work.

```
true_outliers= outliers[ 
        (outliers['isolation_forest_300000']==1) & 
        (outliers['knn_1000']==1) &
        (outliers['knn_10000']==1)&
        (outliers['abod_neighbors_5_1000']==1)&
        (outliers['abod_neighbors_5_10000']==1)&
        (outliers['abod_neighbors_10_1000']==1)&
        (outliers['hbos_1000']==1)&
        (outliers['hbos_10000']==1)&
        (outliers['hbos_100000']==1)]
```

however how can i refactor it like this:

```
for col in outliers.columns.tolist():
     s= outliers[outliers[col] == 1]
```

I want it go thru loop and only select those rows that are '1' in each column

Comment: provide sample data and expected output

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar , thx u ,I m out of trafic in my machine at work,so uploading from phone ,sorry for inconvenience, https://ibb.co/2ggKTLJ

Comment: Try to add `.loc`,like this  `true_outliers=outliers.loc[your condition]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select rows with `1` on every column, using a mask is better

*Sample df*:

```
Out[266]:
   isolation_forest_300000  knn_1000  knn_10000  abod_neighbors_5_1000  \
0                        1         1          1                      1
1                        0         0          0                      1
2                        0         0          0                      0
3                        1         1          1                      1

   abod_neighbors_5_10000  abod_neighbors_10_1000  hbos_1000  hbos_10000  \
0                       1                       1          1           1
1                       1                       0          0           0
2                       0                       0          0           0
3                       1                       1          1           1

   hbos_100000
0            1
1            0
2            0
3            1
```

use `eq` and `all` to create mask and slicing

```
df[df.eq(1).all(1)]

Out[267]:
   isolation_forest_300000  knn_1000  knn_10000  abod_neighbors_5_1000  \
0                        1         1          1                      1
3                        1         1          1                      1

   abod_neighbors_5_10000  abod_neighbors_10_1000  hbos_1000  hbos_10000  \
0                       1                       1          1           1
3                       1                       1          1           1

   hbos_100000
0            1
3            1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you:

```
import functools
import operator
import pandas as pd

data = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=[str(i) for i in range(9)]
)

condition = functools.reduce(
    operator.and_,
    (df[col] == 1 for col in df.columns)
)

print(df[condition])
```